# Double integral for joint uniform PDF and E[XY]

Tags: calculus, probability, definite-integrals, expected-value, density-function

I first want to confirm whether or not if the integral of the following PDF for two joint uniform distributions is equal to 1 for 0 < c < 1:
$$∫_{0}^1 ∫_{max(0, x-1+c)}^{min(1, x+1-c)} \frac{1}{1-c^2}dydx = 1$$

If this is the case, then how can I evaluate the expected value of the products between the two random variables?

$$E[XY] = ∫_{0}^1 ∫_{max(0, x-1+c)}^{min(1, x+1-c)} \frac{xy}{1-c^2}dydx$$